# How to kill travis build with exit code 0 using command?

Tags: travis-ci

Presently we are facing build failure problem in Travis because of https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/7702. I was just wondering if Travis has any command line option to kill it with exit code 0, then I can force travis to terminate 'after_success'. Will be a hacky way to deal with this situation until they solve this bug.

Answer (score 9):

The shell function [`travis_terminate`](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-build/blob/f603c0089116364ccb820cad790b0837f358fb53/lib/travis/build/templates/header.sh#L163-L167) will help.

Alternatively, you can ensure to do `set +e` before the call to `exit`.

`travis_terminate 0` is the best solution at the moment.

Comment: Have a link to a build log?